# Keep website sizes the same

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am having trouble with keeping things aligned on my website. Here is an example of what the website should look like:

[image]

Now, here is where it makes unaligned.. When I resize the window to be smaller, the Text shifts over like so:

[image]

Currently these are the css attributes applied to my  tag which is on the text.

```
#header_title_container {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding-left: 85px;
padding-top: 50px;
}

#header_title {
font-size: 33px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

What would the proper way to approach always having "Title" aligned with the corner of the darkest gray box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because your title container has padding inside it, the text "Title" is kept at least 85px from the screen edge. Because it's left-aligned, that means its left-hand edge is always at 85px.

So, when your sidebar gets smaller than 85px, the text cannot align with it.

You could fix this by fixing the size of the sidebar, by eliminating the padding-left directive and replacing it with an element sized as the sidebar is (or replacing it with the same amount as your sidebar width!), or by setting min-width on the sidebar.

Comment: What part are you referring to when you say "sidebar"?

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: The light gray left-hand box.

Comment: The light grey is just the overall website background color. The dark gray is being centered using margin: 0px auto, and it's width is being directly set to 900px. Would it be better to have a sidebar there?

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: yes. You want an element there if you're going to be controlling the sizing. Set the middle bit (and the new element) to have 0px margins all around, then control the size of the new left-hand element and have the title move with it.

Comment: Ok I did that. But now when the browser window passes the far right hand side of the gray element on the right of the sidebar, It gets pushed down below the sidebar. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: Make sure the sidebar fills from just below the titlebar to the bottom of the page. This can be done by containing the two gray boxes in a div and setting them to `height: 100%`. Then they'll stay side-by-side.

Comment: Ok i wrapped the sidebar and the main element in a <div> tag, I also set the heights of the sidebar and the main body containers to 100%. Still seems to do the same though.. Maybe I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer: they can't end up one-above-the-other if they're both too tall for that to happen. I mean, they can't be height:100% and still be stacked...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6937/discussion-between-duncan-palmer-and-borealid)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of result you are after?

http://jsfiddle.net/2ScZZ/5/

**html**

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="header_title_container">   
    <div id="sub_header_title_container">
      <div id="header_title">
        Title
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="middlebit">      
  </div>  
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container {
background-color: lightgray;  
}

  #header_title_container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  }

    #sub_header_title_container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;   
    }

      #header_title {
      font: 33px verdana;
      color: white;
      padding: 50px 0 10px 0;
      }

  #middlebit {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  }
```

Comment: No it wasn't. But thanks for the help anyway :) I decided to display the logo differently and the way I have it now doesn't cause any problems, you can check out my final decision here http://mymcstatus.net/blackbird/